# why the animation is accelerating

Tags: javascript, svg, pixi.js, grafika

I have problem with my code. Why this animation still accelerates.
[in this link is code ][1]

[1]:`enter code here` http://jsfiddle.net/74j0u5zf/4/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because more than one of your `if` statements can execute each loop.  If x == 500, it is also > 0.

Your `gameLoop()` function can be greatly simplified.

```
function gameLoop() {

    renderer.render(stage);
    cat.x = cat.x + moveX;

    if (cat.x <= 0 || cat.x >= 500) {
        moveX = -moveX;
    }

    requestAnimationFrame(gameLoop);
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/74j0u5zf/5/